# Welche Sprachmodi gibt es im Deutschen?

Tags: grammatical-mood

Dem Wikipediaeintrag über den [grammatischen Modus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_(Grammatik)) zufolge gibt es im Deutschen drei Modi: **Indikativ**, **Konjunktiv** und **Imperativ**; außerdem Umschreibungen mit **Modalverben**.

Es scheint aber weitere zu geben: Optativ, Jussiv und einige mehr, die sich heute (ausschließlich?) im Konjunktiv verstecken oder in festen Wendungen vorkommen, in der Funktion jedoch nicht mit dem Konjunktiv übereinstimmen.

**Welche Modi gibt es in der deutschen Sprache und was drückt man mit ihnen aus?**

Comment: Kommt darauf, was man unter einem Modus versteht - Die pure grammatische Form der Wörter (die hast du mit deiner Liste im ersten Absatz schon abgehakt), im allgemeinen, wie man ein Verb in diese drei Modi flektieren kann, oder was die spezifische Flektion dann bedeutet (*Es werde Licht* bedeutet was anderes, als *Er sagte, er werde wohl alt*, obwohl beides Konjunktiv ist)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Sehr schön. Sollte als Antwort gepostet werden.

Comment: @äüö: Die Frage lautete aber »welche Modi gibt es ...« und mein Kommentar beantwortet diese Frage nicht.

Comment: Wenn man Hubert Schölnast folgt, müsste die Frage als "primarily opinion-based" geschlossen werden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, wie du die Frage stellst, lässt sie sich nur sehr schwer beantworten, daher mache ich auch erst jetzt aus einem Kommentar, den ich vor ziemlich genau 100 Tagen gepostet habe, eine »offizielle« Antwort.

Es kommt sehr darauf an, was man unter einem Modus versteht.
Wenn man damit die pure grammatische Form, also die technische Konstruktion an sich betrachtet, gibt es nur die drei Modi, die du bereits aufgezählt hast.

Eine andere Sichtweise erhält man, wenn man auf die semantische Ebene wechselt, und nach Bedeutungen fragt:

> Gott sprach: »**Es werde Licht**!« und es ward Licht!
>   Rüdiger glaubte, **es werde Licht** wenn jemand in den Raum käme, aber der Sensor war kaput.

Zweimal dieselbe Konstruktion, beide Male Konjunktiv I.

Aber im ersten Beispiel ist es ein Befehl, also etwas, das semantisch schon recht nahe beim Imperativ steht. Germanisten würden das wahrscheinlich als *Optativ* bezeichnen, aber ein »echter« Optativ drückt einen Wunsch aus (*»Lang **lebe** der König«*). Auch der *Jussativ* (*»Man **nehme** drei Eier und eine Priese Salz«*) kommt in Frage.

Das andere Beispiel erinnert an die indirekte Rede, obwohl hier niemand redet oder geredet hat. Grammatisch ist das wahrscheinlich der *coniunctivus obliquus*, der eine innere Abhängigkeit ausdrückt. Weil es sich aber eben nicht um die indirekte Wiedergabe einer Rede handelt, müsste man dafür aber vielleicht doch eine eigene Kategorie definieren.

Je feiner man diese Unterschiede klassifizieren möchte, desto mehr Kategorien braucht man.

---

Genauso gut könnte man auch fragen: *»Wie viele Fälle gibt es im Deutschen?«* In jedem Lehrbuch steht: Es gibt 4 Fälle (Nominativ, Genitiv, Dativ, Akkusativ). Aber ...

- »mit dem Hammer« ist ein Instrumentalis
- »im Schrank« ist ein Lokativ
- »ins Ziel« ein Allativ
- »aus Linz« ein Ablativ und
- »sehr geehrter Herr Huber« ist ein Vokativ.

All diese Fälle werden jetzt im Deutschen mit Präpositionen gebildet, werden in der urindigermanischen Sprache aber als "echte" Fälle behandelt.

Man könnte auch fragen, ob *»**der Toten** gedenken«* und *»Ticket **zweiter Klasse**«* (beides Genitiv) wirklich derselbe Fall ist, oder ob das nicht zwei verschiedene Fälle sind. Auch hier kommt es sehr darauf an, was man unter einem Fall versteht.

Das heißt: Es kommt auf die Definition an. Die einen betrachten nur die Buchstaben und Wörter auf dem Papier und fassen gleiche Konstruktionen zu Kategorien zusammen. Die anderen untersuchen Bedeutungen, und dann zerfallen gleiche sprachliche Konstruktionen natürlich in mehrere verschiedene Klassen.

Beide Sichtweisen sind sinnvoll, aber meist ignoriert man Bedeutungen und betrachtet nur die sprachlichen Konstruktionen.

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese gut verständliche Antwort. Die verschiedenen Arten, sprachliche Strukturen zu betrachten (hier der eher grammatische und der eher semantische Blickwinkel), werden sehr deutlich.